# How to get audio input from home camera?

Tags: camera, nest-api

from https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/api-camera
once i detected “last_event/has_sound” then I’d like to consume the audio content, how? Can I somehow get audio out of “web_url”?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get audio. The message only has a flag that says if the last event had audio in the alert.